# Compute the distance of some nodes using a road layer which are not exactly on the road

Tags: distance, kml, google-earth, road, nodes

I have the road network of a region (downloaded from open street map as a layer) and a set of nodes (selected using google earth, saved as a KML file and finally converted as a layer).

I need to calculate the shortest distance between the nodes using the road (not the Euclidean distance!), remember that some of the nodes are maybe far from the road and not exactly located on. The output should be a matrix distance showing the distance for each pair of nodes.